# Can I use QT Creator for C programming?

Tags: c, linux, qt-creator

Can I use QT Creator for C (not C++) non-GUI programming on Linux?

Or is it just for C++ + QT?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Of course you can. Just add QT -= core gui to your qmake .pro file and your project isn't going to be linked with Qt libraries.